# Error in folder structure using typescript, expo and react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I set up a new typescript project on react native using expo and tried to use "src" as the folder structure
`tsconfig.json` is defined like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/App.tsx"],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

The main error is this

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
iOS Bundling failed 29ms
Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
› Reloading apps
iOS Bundling failed 7ms
Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
› Reloading apps
iOS Bundling failed 4ms
Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
```

my folder
[image: folder_structure]

I tried all the methods used in other topics related to this on stackverflow but nothing that was similar helped

Answer (score 0):

It is because react-native won't be able to find the AppEntry.js. You can see that path in the `package.json` file in the `main` property. One thing you can do is create `App.tsx` on the route directory and add this code and my suggestion is that rename the `App.tsx` file inside the `src` folder with something else so it will not confuse you like `Main.tsx`.

```
import Main from "./src/Main";

export default () => {
  return <Main />;
};
```